# Javascript working in Firefox, but not IE, Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, google-chrome

First time making a Javascript script from scratch. This works perfectly in Firefox, but when viewed in Chrome or Safari the right sidebar doesn't change opacity at all. This was designed so that when the mouse hovers over the sidebar div, it changes the opacity of the arrow img within that div. The left sidebar is set to be the same, but changes opacity of the div and img.

I designed it this way as the client wanted to see what both look like before coming to a decision which one to keep. Once that decision is made it will just be one or the other, so I need to get the right sidebar fixed up!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Giterman Designs</title>     
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 


<script type="text/javascript">
function changeOpacity(elm, value) {
   elm.style.opacity = (value / 100);
   elm.style.MozOpacity = (value / 100);
   elm.style.KhtmlOpacity = (value / 100);
   elm.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (value) + ")";
   elm.style.MsFilter = " 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=" + (value) + ")' ";}
</script>

</head> 
<body>

<!-- Left Side: Hover over Div, Div+Image shifts opacity -->
<div id="leftNav" class="sidebar" onMouseOver="changeOpacity(this, 70)" onMouseOut="changeOpacity(this, 20)">
    <img src="image/leftNav.png" id="leftButton" class="arrow" alt=""></div>

<!-- Right Side: Hover over Div, Image shifts opacity -->       
<div id="rightNav" class="sidebar2" onMouseOver="changeOpacity(rightButton, 70)" onMouseOut="changeOpacity(rightButton, 20)">
    <img src="image/rightNav.png" id="rightButton" class="arrow" alt=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
body{
background: url("image/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;}

div#leftNav{
position:absolute; left:0;}

div#rightNav{
position:absolute; right:0;}

/* Left Side-bar */
.sidebar{
background:#000000; width: 55px; height: 100%; top:0; opacity:0.20;}

/* Right Side-bar */
.sidebar2{
background: url("image/bar.png") repeat-y; width: 55px; height: 100%; top:0;}

/* Needed to seperate arrow opacity for Right Side-bar attempt */
#rightButton{
opacity: 0.20;}

img.arrow{
position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: 0 0 0 -35%;}
```

Comment: Just a comment: why don't you use CSS `:hover` pseudo class? You could use `.sidebar:hover img.arrow {opacity: 0.5}`.

Comment: I would have used the hover if it were not for needing the opacity of the child altered on hover of the parent. I do not/did not know how to do that.

Comment: If you do not need to do something complex by hovering over a `div` and changing the css of an element from another place, `:hover` will perfectly do it. Here's an example with your code http://jsfiddle.net/nyt5b/. You can check out the CSS part to get a better idea. Hover your mouse over the left and right where the buttons are, the child element `#rightButton` and `#leftButton` will change opacity.
For performance and maintenance considerations: less code, less work, less bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code for left:

```
onMouseOver="changeOpacity(this, 70)"
```

but for right you are not using this:

```
onMouseOver="changeOpacity(rightButton, 70)"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow. As I said in my statement, the left hand side is meant so that the Div and child image within have their opacity change.

The right hand side is supposed to have it so that when the mouse is over "sidebar2" it alters the opacity of "rightButton".

However it is only working in Firefox currently, not any other web browser. In Chrome, Safari and IE it does nothing onMouseOver for the right side.

Comment: Then you should not pass in rightButton as the parameter, instead of that use getElementByID('rightButton') to replace rightButton in the call

Comment: Thanks! I thought I would be able to pass rightButton through, but I guess Chrome and Safari aren't pleased.